# Error when installing through Pip - Windows

Tags: python, django, pip

When trying to install Django through pip we get an error message.

So it's an protocol error, and then since he has in Swedish it says something like:

> "a try was made to get access to a socket in a way that is forbidden by the table of access"....

It seems like we need any admin access or something? We tried to run the command prompt as an administrator. By marking the "run as administrator" box in the command prompt settings. We are lost, any help is greatly appreciated.

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10013, 'Ett f\xf6rs\xf6k gjordes att f\xe5 \xe5tkomst till en socket p\xe5 ett s\xe4tt som \xe4r f\xf6rbjudet av \xe5tkomstbeh\xf6righeterna'))': /simple/django/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for django

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pip? This tends to happen when you are not up to date. Check https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-7.1.0.tar.gz
You'll need to download, untar and install this manually through `setup.py install`. Check also for updated dependencies, such as setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that python.exe is allowed in your firewall settings and any antivirus firewall settings. I had the same problems, and had to allow the program under my AVG firewall settings cause it still wouldn't work even after I had allowed it under Windows firewall.